# How can i install deleted default api service in kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, nginx-ingress, kubernetes-apiserver

I am on Kubernetes v1.22.13. When i was trying to delete a namespace that's stuck in status `terminating`, i deleted api-service `v1.networking.k8s.io` by mistake with:

```
kubectl delete apiservices.apiregistration.k8s.io v1.networking.k8s.io
```

And now i don't have crds related to `v1.networking.k8s.io` such as `Ingress`.  When i try to install ingress-controller it gives the error:

> error: resource mapping not found for name: "nginx" namespace: "" from "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/controller-v1.4.0/deploy/static/provider/cloud/deploy.yaml": no matches for kind "IngressClass" in version "networking.k8s.io/v1"

How can i undo that operation? Or how can i bring back api-resource `v1.networking.k8s.io`?

Tried to find a way to undo it and install it manually but i couldn't find the manifest related to that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can recreate it via the following:

```
cat <<EOF | kubectl apply -f -
apiVersion: apiregistration.k8s.io/v1
kind: APIService
metadata:
  labels:
    kube-aggregator.kubernetes.io/automanaged: onstart
  name: v1.networking.k8s.io
spec:
  group: networking.k8s.io
  groupPriorityMinimum: 17200
  version: v1
  versionPriority: 15
EOF
```

Comment: Thanks! I guess this yaml is taken from working k8s deployment , but is there option to regenerate it on the fly from some original repo or recover internally considering it is a general api  that is must have for other nested configurations on top?

Comment: I am not aware of any :/

Comment: Yea actually this works but i was also hoping if there's a way to do it without relying on existing cluster.